# Flatten master/detail entity

Tags: entity-framework, optimization, linq-to-sql, nested-loops, gmap.net

I have the following tables in my Sql Sever Database:

Tbl_Polygons:
   PolygonId,
   PolygonName

Tbl_PolygonPoints:
   pointId,
   Fk_PolygonId,
   Latitude,
   Longitude
I'm using following method to read each polygon then its points:

```
Using context = New myDbEntities()
Dim polygons = (From poly In context.Tbl_Polygons Select Poly).ToList()

polygons.ForEach(Sub(ply)
                             Dim polyPoint = (From pPoint In Tbl_PolygonPoints Where pPoint.Fk_PolygonId = ply.PolygonId
                                              Select pPoint.Latitude, pPoint.Longitude).ToList()


                             polyPoint.ForEach(Sub(pPoint)
                                                   polygonPoints.Add(New PointLatLng(pPoint.Latitude, pPoint.Longitude))
                                               End Sub)

                             DrawPolygon(ply,polygonPoints)
                             polygonPoints.Clear()
                         End Sub)
End Using
```

I have about 20000 polygons in my table. 
the code mentioned above taking too long to run completely.
I was trying to flatten my data then I can remove my inner ForEach loop.
Does SelectMany will solve my problem? if yes any suggestions are appreciated

many thanks

Comment: The model is not clear anyway you can insert AsNoTracking, Include, and also flatten with Select to improve performances. Usually AsNoTracking and Include is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response but adding AsNoTracking does not have marking effect. I just want read polygons from tbl_polygons then its points from tbl_polygonpoints with linq in a effective way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a comment but it's too long.

Include has the same effect of SelectMany, you avoid 20.000 queries. In both cases you need to have a model with navigation properties. The code is usually more clear if you use Include.
Then, the second optimization will be to insert AsNoTracking to avoid to add several entities to the context. In your case you could use code first from database so you start from your database and you write a model. With this model  (sorry about c#, I can read VB but I can't write it)

```
[Table("Tbl_Polygons")]
class Polygon
{
    [Key]
    public int PolygonId {get; set;}
    public string PolygonName {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Point> Points {get; set;}
}

[Table("Tbl_PolygonPoints")]
public Point
{
    [Key]
    public int PointId {get; set;}
    public int Latitude {get; set;}
    public int Lontitude {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("Fk_PolygonId")]
    public virtual Polygon Polygon {get; set;}
    public int Fk_PolygonId {get; set;}
}
```

your code will be this.

```
var polygons = context.Polygons.Include(p => p.Points).AsNoTracking().ToList();
foreach (var polygon in polygons)
    DrawPolygon(polygon, polygon.Points)
```

You can obtain that ef runs only 1 query also using SelectMany but the result of the query is a list of points with a property that is the polygon so in the foreach you need to retrieve the groups of points of the same polygon (so, in your case, the code will be less clear).

Comment: Thank you... I will check it

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Now I'm going to build hierarchical list from this flat list.